# Change color depending on value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't why this is not working. Can somebody tell me what is the problem with this?

```
var x = $('#clicked_info').val();

if(x == 1) {

    $('#companyname_ph').css({'color':'yellow'});

}

else if(x == 2) {

    $('#companyname_ph').css({'color':'red'});

}
```

Comment: What's `#clicked_info`? Are you sure it contains either `1` or `2`?

Comment: This could use some more context. For instance, are you expecting the CSS to be applied when the value changes or just on page load? You're getting answers about string vs. number comparisons which *can* make it fail (so using parseInt() is a good practice), but it could just as well succeed and you might be seeing some other problem.

Comment: Is it an `<input>`, or something else? A wild guess: if you're trying to get the text content, use `.text()`, not `.val()`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `parseInt` to convert a string to an integer.

```
var x = $('#clicked_info').val();

if(parseInt(x) == 1){

   $('#companyname_ph').css({'color':'yellow'});

} else if(parseInt(x) == 2){

    $('#companyname_ph').css({'color':'red'});

}
```

**OR** use string comparison

```
if(x == '1'){
```

Comment: I might add here that if you're converting the string to integer, then might as well as the `===` comparison operator instead of `==`.

Comment: I think javascript already doing that, when you compare `'1' == 1` it return false. You don't need to write `'1' === 1`

Comment: Yaah, it will process `1 == '1'` :)

Answer (score 1):

`val` returns a `string`

`x == 1` shoulb be `x == '1'`

`x == 2` should be `x == '2'`

Or you can convert `x` to int using the following.

```
var x = $('#clicked_info').val();
x = parseInt(x);
```

Comment: `1 == '1'`. This shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

like the other folks here have noted, you should use `parseInt` when you want to convert a string representation of an integer to a number type. I would add that you should provide a radix to `parseInt` because if you don't, you may get unexpected results if your string starts unexpectedly with "0x" :)

try doing:

```
var x = parseInt($('#clicked_info').val(), 10)
```

Comment: Not only will you get unexpected results if your string beings with `0x` (hexadecimal), you'll also get unexpected results if your string begins with `0` (octal), which is far more common than 0x.